# Localhost redirection

Tags: php, apache, ip, localhost

I have installed `XAMPP` on a Windows 7 machine. The `localhost` directory is `C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\xampp\xampp\htdocs`

Now I design a website in another directory on a different drive : `D:\HTML\Site1`

How can I reference the website directory from the browser? I would prefer not to change the configuration file for `httpd`. Is a symlink the best option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do a symlink, or you could set up a virtual host to access the directory